# Loop Subset of Sheets Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, loops, worksheet-function

I want to loop through a subset of sheets in Excel using VBA. I want to define the list of sheets in a single sheet, then I want loop through that list. Below i have the code to loop through the whole book, but what I want is just to loop through the subset of sheets I define. What I envision is defining a range of sheets then looping through that range. Any insight would be appreciated.

```
Sub cyclethroughwbs()

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
ws.Select
ws.Calculate

Next ws

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Say *Sheet1* has the list of  worksheets to process in column **A**:

[image]

This code will loop over them:

```
Sub LoopOverListOfSheets()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        N = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 1 To N
            Sheets(.Cells(i, "A").Value).Select
            Sheets(.Cells(i, "A").Value).Calculate
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Why would you select the sheet before calculating it?

Answer (score 0):

I propose two different techniques, both dealing with possible blank cells and non existent worksheet

the first is a "nearly all-in-one" sub

```
Option Explicit

Sub LoopOverListOfSheets()
Dim shtNamesRng As Range, cell As Range
Dim sht As Worksheet

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetWithNames")
    Set shtNamesRng = .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)
End With

For Each cell In shtNamesRng
    Set sht = SetSheet(ThisWorkbook, cell.Value)
    If Not sht Is Nothing Then
        With sht
            .Calculate
            '... other code on "sht"
        End With
    End If
Next cell

End Sub


Function SetSheet(wb As Workbook, shtName As String) As Worksheet

On Error Resume Next
Set SetSheet = wb.Worksheets(shtName)
On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

the second solution uses more "wrapper" functions to keep code clean and maintainable. it also uses Collection object to simply deal with no sheets found at all

```
Option Explicit

Sub LoopOverListOfSheets2()
Dim shtsColl As Collection
Dim sht As Worksheet

Set shtsColl = GetSheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetWithNames"))

For Each sht In shtsColl
'    sht.Calculate
    '...
Next sht

End Sub


Function GetSheets(namesSht As Worksheet) As Collection
Dim myColl As New Collection
Dim shtNamesRng As Range, cell As Range
Dim sht As Worksheet

With namesSht
    Set shtNamesRng = .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)

    For Each cell In shtNamesRng
        Set sht = SetSheet(namesSht.Parent, cell.Value)
        If Not sht Is Nothing Then myColl.Add sht
    Next cell
End With

Set GetSheets = myColl

End Function


Function SetSheet(wb As Workbook, shtName As String) As Worksheet

On Error Resume Next
Set SetSheet = wb.Worksheets(shtName)
On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```